# What is the power of a recursive language vs. that of one that is recursively enumerable?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability

I am simply wondering, as the title states, what the central differences are between recursive and recursively enumerable languages?  If I am not mistaken a recursive language is a is Turing decidable while a recursively enumerable one is only Turing recognizable but I suspect that is either wrong or does not capture the whole picture.  Can anybody give a brief answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursive / Turing-decidable languages have a Turing machine that can always decide in finite time whether a word is in the language.

Recursively enumerable / RE / Turing-recognizable languages have a Turing machine that will accept a word in the language in finite time, but not necessarily stop to reject a word that's not in the language.

Recursive implies RE but not vice versa.

A language and its complement are RE if and only if the language is recursive (which is equivalent to saying that the complement of the language is recursive).